# How to call a function on click on menu option?

Tags: android

I want to have on menu button click to call a function,
that function will popup a window with place for input.
I added to the activity_main.xml the following line

```
android:onClick="getURL"
```

and have defined a function in my mainActivity.java:

```
public void getURL(View view) {...}
```

however, when i load the app i get:

```
01-31 09:59:13.479: E/AndroidRuntime(761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 09:59:13.479: E/AndroidRuntime(761): android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler getURL in class com.example.remoteswitch.MainActivity
```

my menu settings looks like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    android:onClick="getURL"/>
```

any ideas why it happens to me?

Comment: What menu button? Is it a Menu item defined in the `Options Menu`? If the _menu button_ you speak of is in a layout xml, post the code for that.

Comment: Yes. thats the one, I added it to main post

Answer (score 6):

The way you handle the click on a `Menu Item` is like this:

First, setup your Options Menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater mnuInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    mnuInflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_xml, menu);        
    return true;
}
```

Handle the clicks here:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        // EITHER CALL THE METHOD HERE OR DO THE FUNCTION DIRECTLY
        yourMethod();

        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And do the function in the `yourMethod()` here:

```
private void yourMethod() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}
```

I am not sure if the `onClick` method is valid / works when it comes to an `Options Menu`. The above code works as it should anyway.

Comment: @e-r-a-n: Glad to have helped. :-)

Comment: I'd remove the last part of this answer.The `onClick` method IS a valid way to use the `Options Menu`

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menuxml_name, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId())    
    {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            getURL();   
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Try these override methods into activity so that it can be easy to perform your operation

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something to an old post:
First of all, the parameter of your method should have been `MenuItem` not `View` (Bet you already knew that).Secondly, from the official google developer website, it says:

> Tip: Android 3.0 adds the ability for you to define the on-click behavior for a menu item in XML, using the android:onClick attribute. The value for the attribute must be the name of a method defined by the activity using the menu. The method must be public and accept a single MenuItem parameter—when the system calls this method, it passes the menu item selected. For more information and an example, see the Menu Resource document.

To use this option, define a method (the method you want to call when the options menu item is clicked) in your activity.For example:

```
 public void showOptionMenuItem(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
          "You have selected the GET URL option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

and then in your XML, you do this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

  ...

<item android:id="@+id/getUrl"
    android:onClick="getURL" //<----
    android:title="@string/get_url"/>

</menu>
```